# Python Pickle append returns "None" rather than user's input

Tags: python, append, pickle

```
post=input(str("Enter your post below: \n"))
addpost=pickle.dump(post, open("The Wall.txt","ab"))
print(addpost)
```

Have no idea why this code returns "None" rather than what is typed in...

Answer (score 4):

Because `pickle.dump` writes the object to the file, and returns `None`.

You probably want

```
addpost = pickle.load(open("The Wall.txt", "rb"))
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to add 'post' to The Wall.txt but not replace everything that's already on there?(just adding to the bottom)

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `pickle` to write to a text file, actually. Why not just do `open("The Wall.txt", "ab").write(post)`? You really only need `pickle` if you'll be writing arbitrary Python objects (like class instances, dictionaries or lists) to a file.

Comment: sorry i'm kinda new so i don't know many different ways to write to files, that seems better so thanks :)

Comment: TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: Oh, you're using Python 3. In that case, use `open("The Wall.txt", "a")` to open the file in text mode (instead of binary mode). That will allow you to write strings to the file.